# What is the opposite of "digital"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was reading [an article](https://www.facebook.com/MtGox/posts/484532824964463):

> While Bitcoin's power lies in its ability to transfer fast and
>   securely through software, the rest of the financial world does not
>   operate like that (contrary to popular opinion). **Money is surprisingly
>   analog in many ways, and scarily digital in others.**

Is analog actually the opposite of digital?

What other better alternatives are there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Analog*, meaning non-quantized (i.e. capable of smooth variation), has become the word most often used to express a contrast to *digital* by default, even in cases where it may not be strictly appropriate.  (It often forms the modifier in a *retronym*, a new word or phrase used to distinguish the original version of something from a newer rival.)

Analog probably became the word of choice after its use in *analog recording* (as opposed to digital recording technologies such as CDs) and *analog watch* (as opposed to digital watches).  In both cases it was appropriate because the smoothly varying analog signal was a direct contrast to the quantized digital experience.

In this particular case, even non-digital money is quantized, but *analog* at least has the advantage of being readily understood.

Comment: +1 for the *retronym* reference. I didn't know that word, but it's a handy concept.

Comment: Ironically many analog watches have a *ticking* second hand, a stepwise movement, the product of an escapement menchanism that transforms the analog action pressure of a spring into a digital-like process.

Answer (score 3):

Analogue - Relating to or using signals or information represented by a continuously variable physical quantity such as spatial position or voltage.

Digital - (of signals or data) expressed as series of the digits 0 and 1, typically represented by values of a physical quantity such as voltage or magnetic polarization.

Analogue uses Continuous Variables whilst Digital uses Discrete. Analogue is more physical than digital, like watches. Analogue watches use spatial position (a continuous variable) whilst Digital watches use 0s and 1s to show their information, which is discrete, and not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The article might be referring to the paper money as analog while referring to the internet banking / credit card swipe transactions as digital.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be so ...

Answer (score -2):

I think you can just use the word 'traditional', because compared with 'digital' circuit, analog circuit is traditional

Comment: Completely out of context...

Comment: And also completely incorrect. ‘Traditional’ is not a synonym for ‘analogue’. A traditional watch can easily be digital, and an analogue watch can easily be very untraditional.

Comment: What would a traditional digital watch look like?